# View or function 'ABC' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables

Tags: sql, nhibernate, icriteria

I have a view:

```
    CREATE VIEW [SZV].[ViewMembership]
AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
                         a.ID, a.RIZIVNr, a.Denomination, a.FirstInsDate, c.ID AS HcwId, e.BCEKBO AS CbeEstablishmentNr, d.ID AS TypeCodeId, d.Code AS TypeCodeCode, d.DescriptionNL, 
                         d.DescriptionFR, g.ID AS TypeSitCodeId, g.Code AS SitCode, g.DescriptionFR AS SitDescriptionFR, g.DescriptionNL AS SitDescriptionNL, f.ID AS SitCodeId, 
                         f.SitBegDate, f.SitEndDate, c.RIZIVNr AS LidRizivNr, a.LastSitID, c.LastSitID AS MemberLastSitID, n.Code AS MemberSitCode, 
                         n.DescriptionFR AS MemberSitDescriptionFR, n.DescriptionNL AS MemberSitDescriptionNL, j.FirstName1, j.FirstName2, j.LastName, j.INSS, 
                         h.FromDate AS StartDatum, k.Code AS RolCode, k.DescriptionFR AS RolDescriptionFR, k.DescriptionNL AS RolDescriptionNL, h.ToDate AS EindDatum, 
                         m.ID AS AddressId, m.Street, m.StreetNr, m.Box, m.Locality, m.ZipCode, m.INSCode, p.AttributeValueID AS AttributValueId, p.AttributeID, r.Code AS AttributeCode, 
                         q.AttributeValue, s.Code AS ProfCodeCode, s.DescriptionNL AS ProfDescriptionNL, s.DescriptionFR AS ProfDescriptionFR, h.ID AS HcwSitId, u.ID AS RequestId, 
                         u.HCWID AS RequestForId, x.RIZIVNr AS RequestedForRizivNr, u.ToDate AS RequestToDate, u.FromDate AS RequestFromDate, u.RequestedBy, 
                         v.Code AS RequestRolCode, v.DescriptionFR AS RequestRolDescriptionFR, v.DescriptionNL AS RequestRolDescriptionNL, 
                         w.FirstName1 + ' ' + w.LastName AS RequestedByName, y.FirstName1 AS RequestedForFirstName1, y.FirstName2 AS RequestedForFirstName2, 
                         y.LastName AS RequestedForLastName, y.INSS AS RequestedForINSS, z.ID AS HciAttributeRequestId, z.RequestedBy AS HciAttributeRequestedBy
FROM            SZV.HCI AS a INNER JOIN
                         SZV.HCWHCI AS b ON a.ID = b.HCIID INNER JOIN
                         SZV.HCW AS c ON b.HCWID = c.ID INNER JOIN
                         Param.TypeCode AS d ON d.ID = a.TypeCodeID INNER JOIN
                         SZV.Org AS e ON e.ID = a.OrgID INNER JOIN
                         SZV.HCISit AS f ON f.ID IN
                             (SELECT        MAX(ID) AS Expr1
                               FROM            SZV.HCISit
                               WHERE        (HCIID = a.ID)) INNER JOIN
                         Param.TypeSitCode AS g ON g.ID = f.SitCodeID INNER JOIN
                         SZV.HCWHCI AS h ON h.HCIID = a.ID AND h.HCWID = c.ID INNER JOIN
                         SZV.HCWSit AS o ON o.HCWID = c.ID INNER JOIN
                         Param.TypeSitCode AS n ON n.ID = o.SitCodeID INNER JOIN
                         SZV.Person AS j ON j.ID = c.PersonID INNER JOIN
                         Param.HCWRole AS k ON h.RoleID = k.ID INNER JOIN
                         SZV.HCIAddress AS l ON l.HCIID = a.ID INNER JOIN
                         Param.ProfCode AS s ON s.ID = c.ProfCodeID INNER JOIN
                         SZV.Address AS m ON m.ID = l.AddressID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         SZV.HCIAttribute AS p ON p.HCIID = a.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Param.AttributeValue AS q ON p.AttributeValueID = q.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Param.Attribute AS r ON r.ID = p.AttributeID AND r.Code = 'TherapeuticLink' LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         SZV.HCWHCIRequest AS u ON u.HCIID = a.ID AND u.HCWID = c.ID AND u.Validated = 0 AND u.Canceled = 0 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Param.HCWRole AS v ON u.RoleID = v.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         SZV.Person AS w ON w.INSS = u.RequestedBy LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         SZV.HCW AS x ON u.HCWID = x.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         SZV.Person AS y ON x.PersonID = y.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         SZV.HCIAttributeRequest AS z ON z.HCIID = a.ID AND z.Validated = 0 AND z.Canceled = 0
WHERE        (d.Code IN ('805', '212', '214'))
```

Now when I use NHibernate to get my result I get the following error :
{"View or function 'SZV.ViewMembership' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables."}

> {"View or function 'SZV.ViewMembership' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables."}

The code I use is the following :

```
ICriteria selectCriteria = this.CreateCriteria();
var or = Restrictions.Disjunction();

if (groupId != 0)
{
    var restrHciId = Restrictions.Eq("Id", groupId);
    or.Add(restrHciId);
}

selectCriteria.Add(or);
IList<Group> groupsList = this.Find(selectCriteria).ToList();
```

I am not trying to update anything in the view.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: In a nutshell.. your mapping is incorrect .. e.g. NULLABLE bit from DB is mapped as C# bool. Any null value .. loaded from DB is therefore converted into false.. and object is dirty. Later, when session is about to sync.. NHiberante sends WRITE statements to DB. Fix? - make your mapping correct. try to use mutable setting..

Comment: @RadimKöhler I'm not quite sure what you mean. Can you please explain some more?

Comment: Try to call the query as read only: `this.Find(selectCriteria).SetReadOnly(true).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

You can only update One table in a "Update Query" for a View;
for two Col from multiple  Tables You have to Use multiple queries :)